# tsnames.ora file in Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.2

Tags: oracle, macos

I need to use the file `tsnames.ora` in a macOS Sierra 10.12.2 but I don't know where it is located.

```
MacBook-Pro-de-lopes: lopes$ locate tsnames.ora

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.
```

Comment: did you install the oracle client on your mac? if yes the tnsnames.ora should be located in: <path_to_your_oracle_client>/network/admin/
If it doesn't exist you can create it and also create the tnsnames.ora file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mac OSX only the [instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html) is available. 
But this client does not bring a sample tnsnames.ora file.

So unless you or an application put a tnsnames.ora file somewhere, it's just not there.

In case you create a tnsnames.ora file with proper content, you need to set ORACLE_HOME or TNS_ADMIN environment variable. instant client has some small differences to default client installation, so please read the [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/ic-faq-094177.html#A4428) for details.